# Generic Method Return Type as Type parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have an extension method that is working ok to cast string values into various types, which looks something like this:

```
public static T ToType<T> (this string value, T property)
    {
        object parsedValue = default(T);
        Type type = property.GetType();

        try
        {
            parsedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            parsedValue = null;
        }

        return (T)parsedValue;
    }
```

I'm unhappy about the way this looks when calling the method, however:

```
myObject.someProperty = stringData.ToType(myObject.someProperty);
```

Specifying the property just to obtain the property's type seems redundant.  I would rather use a signature like this:

```
public static T ToType<T> (this string value, Type type) { ... }
```

and have T end up to be the Type of type.  This would make calls much cleaner:

```
myObject.someProperty = stringData.ToType(typeof(decimal));
```

When I try to call this way, however, the editor complains that the return type of the extension method can't be infered from usage.  Can I link T to the Type argument?

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: *Can I link T to the Type argument?* — Not directly¹. You are mixing up compile-time and runtime. The C# compiler has to decide what `T` is when it processes a call to `ToType` while compiling your code. OTOH `type` assumes a potentially different value every time `ToType` is called.
---------------------------------------------------------
¹ — you *can* use one of the flavors of dynamic compilation, but it's an advanced technique and best reserved for the few cases when it's really necessary.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers and input.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I've added an extra catch for cases where the cast isn't valid also

```
Decimal i = stringName.ToType<Decimal>();

public static T ToType<T>(this string value)
{
     object parsedValue = default(T);
     try
     {
         parsedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
     }
     catch (InvalidCastException)
     {
         parsedValue = null;
     }
     catch (ArgumentException)
     {
         parsedValue = null;
     }
     return (T)parsedValue;
}
```

**Edit**

a shortcut approach to fix Anton's comment

```
if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
   return default(T);
```

Comment: "Specifing the type argument specifically" is exactly what he's doing in the first line of his code. It's a special method-calling syntax using the angle-brackets, though it should work for your case.

Comment: Sorry, Sayse.  It works.  I was omitting the <Decimal> from teh call

Comment: @Sayse btw your code is buggy, `null` cannot be cast to `T` if `T` is a value type. The usual workaround is to have two versions of this method, one for value types returning a `T?` and anotuer for reference types returning `T`.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy - You are correct, I hadn't tested this with value types although I do not believe the OP to be using them, thanks

Comment: One of expected types is decimal, and I've updated the exception paths to revert parsedValue to default(T)

Comment: @ZuluAlphaCharlie - I've updated a little snippet that is a shortcut to what Anton mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Why use property at all? Just change how you're setting your type variable to the type of your generic.

```
    public static T ToType<T>(this string value)
    {
        object parsedValue = default(T);
        Type type = typeof(T);

        try
        {
            parsedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            parsedValue = null;
        }

        return (T) parsedValue;
    }
```

Usage:

```
myObject.someProperty = stringData.ToType<decimal>()
```

Comment: Aha!  I forgot about specifying T in the call ... ToType<decimal>()!  This works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this for a generic conversion:

```
    public bool ConvertTo<T>(object from, out T to) {
        to = default(T);
        if (from is T) { to = (T)from; return true; }                                           
        Type t = typeof(T);
        //TypeConverter converter = p.converter == null ? TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t) : p.converter;
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t);
        if ((converter != null) && (converter.CanConvertTo(t))) {
            try { to = (T)converter.ConvertTo(null, culture, from, t); return true; }
            catch { }
        }
        try { to = (T)Convert.ChangeType(from, t, culture); return true; }
        catch { }
        return false;                                                                                       
    }

    public bool ConvertTo(object from, out object to, Type type) {
        to = null;
        if (from.GetType() == type) { to = from; return true; }     
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
        if ((converter != null) && (converter.CanConvertTo(type))) {
            try { to = converter.ConvertTo(null, culture, from, type); return true; }
            catch { }
        }
        try { to = Convert.ChangeType(from, type, culture); return true; }
        catch { }
        return false;                                           
    }
```

Before calling `Convert.ChangeType`, this checks if there is a `TypeConverter` for the given variable.

Call it this way:

```
int i = 123;
string s;
if (ConvertTo<string>(i, out s) {
    // use s
}
```