# Inverse .ToString()

Tags: c#, types, converters

I'm searching for a general way to convert strings to a type.
For example:

```
class SomeThing<T> {

    public void Add(T value) {
       //...
    }

    public void Add(string value) {
        // Try to convert from string to T ???
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SomeThing<double> list = new SomeThing<double>();
list.Add(123.45);
list.Add("234.56");
```

It should have there features:
 - If the type supports convertion from string, convert it.
 - If the type does not support convertion from string, either throw exception or return `default(T)`.
 - For numbers (double, int) it should use invariant culture.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Add some examples of use... It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Duplicate? [Generic method conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17817407/1324033)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing something like this:

```
public void AddRange(string value) {
  var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

  if (!Object.Reference(converter, null))
    if (converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(String)) {
      T result = (T) converter.ConvertFrom(value);

      // value is converted to T; your code here   
      ...

      return; 
    } 

  // Type T can't be obtained from String directly
  //   1. Do it using by-ways (spesific for particular T's)
  //   2. Use default(T)  
  //   3. Throw exception
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
class SomeThing<T>
{

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        //...
    }

    public void Add(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            T typedValue;
            typedValue = (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromInvariantString(value);
            //Call Add with the converted value
            this.Add(typedValue);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

if you want Add to return default value, use this:

```
class SomeThing<T>
{

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        //...
    }

    public void Add(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            T typedValue;
            typedValue = (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromInvariantString(value);
            //Call Add with the converted value
            this.Add(typedValue);
        }
        catch
        {
            this.Add(default(T));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to convert String to Double like in your example :

```
String myString = "123456";
Double myDouble
Double.TryParse(text, out myDouble);
```

TryParse is not only on Double type.